# Does this not obey the DRY principle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement

I'm trying to respect the ruby principle of keeping my code dry; however, in my conditional, I have different constants set to different days. But that's the only thing different. They're pretty much the same code minus the evaluation of days `from_now`.

```
if term_type == TERM_MONTH 
  MONTHLY_WARNING_1.from_now && send_notice
else 
  ANNUAL_WARNING_1.from_now && send_notice
end
```

I tried using the ternary operator; however, it didn't produce the results I was expecting as it was only setting the days based on `term_type` yet not sending the mail based on it.

```
days = term_type == TERM_MONTH ? MONTHLY_WARNING_1 : ANNUAL_WARNING_1
days.from_now && send_notice
```

A point in the right direction will be helpful. TIA.

Updated to remove noise.

Comment: There's a lot of business logic in here we'd have to infer, if you just want this refactored, probably better for CodeReview.

Comment: @Anthony I've removed the noise. Apologies.

Comment: I've moved this over to CodeReview... thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Unrelated to its DRYness, does this code actually work? I don't think `from_now` ever returns `nil` or `false`, so unless I'm mistaken (which may be the case), both branches will evaluate to the result of `send_notice`.

Comment: @Jordan it's a rails method `irb(main):002:0> subscription.suspended_at < 14.days.from_now => false`. I'm not checking if `from_now` is nil.

Comment: I know what it is and I know that's not what you're trying to do. What I'm saying is that if `from_now` never returns `false` or `nil` (and I believe that's the case) then you are essentially doing `true && send_notice` in *both* branches, which makes branching pointless. You could replace this entire `if … else … end` with just `send_notice` and it would do the exact same thing it does now under all circumstances.

Comment: @Jordan My bad. I'm going to delete this question because it's butchered to hell. I've opened another question relating to it http://stackoverflow.com/q/35496647/4126841 hopefully I convey my issue a little better.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first make sure you understand, what `&&` means and how to use it.

In your code snippet both lines will be evaluated to sending notice only, since whatever you have in either `MONTHLY_WARNING_1.from_now` or `ANNUAL_WARNING_1.from_now` is truthy (unless it is `false` or `nil`).

I think you'd be wanting something like this (split code into smaller chunks by moving some logic into its own method):

```
def warning
  term_type == TERM_MONTH ? MONTHLY_WARNING_1 : ANNUAL_WARNING_1
end

warning.from_now # first set warning or whatever it does
send_notice      # now send the notice
```